# How to count number of files that the latest time was worked on was yesterday

Tags: mysql, date, max, where-clause

I have multiple tables and i want to check the number of files allocated to a user and he has not worked on the files today. i have written the query below but am getting an erro below

## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

```
SELECT t2.id as id,t2.task_date,t3.id as debtor_id,t1.cfid as cfid, t2.cfid,t2.case_file,t2.scheduled_action,t2.debtor 
FROM task_list t2 
INNER JOIN case_files t1 
ON t2.cfid=t1.cfid 
INNER JOIN case_file_allocations t3 
ON t2.cfid=t3.cfid 
WHERE t2.worked<>'yes' 
AND MAX(t2.task_date) < NOW() 
AND t2.acm=t3.acm 
AND t2.acm='310'  
AND t2.deleted<>1 
AND t1.closed<>'yes' 
AND t1.deleted<>1 
AND t1.pool_id IN(0,1) 
AND t3.reallocated<>'yes'  
ORDER BY t2.task_date ASC
```

Kindly check the error for me

Comment: the error is referring to `max(..)`

Comment: I tthought i would use max() o count only records not worked till yesterday

Comment: what does `MAX(t2.task_date)` mean in your query?

Comment: i need to find only number of files in task_list table that the latest time worked in is yesterday

Comment: so the same task may show up multiple times in that table, and you are interested in the newest record?

Comment: No, it is the cfid that shows multiple times in task_list table because whenever someone works on a file i record it in task_list table and the cfid are contained in case_files table too @Fabricator

Comment: So i wanted to get the number of case_files with their maximum task_date not greater than yesterday @Fabricator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the max date for each case file, then count how many qualifies in the outer query:

```
select count(*)
from (
  SELECT t1.cfid as cfid, MAX(t2.task_date) d
  FROM task_list t2 
  INNER JOIN case_files t1 ON t2.cfid=t1.cfid 
  INNER JOIN case_file_allocations t3 ON t2.cfid=t3.cfid 
  WHERE t2.worked<>'yes' AND t2.acm=t3.acm AND t2.acm='310' AND t2.deleted<>1 
    AND t1.closed<>'yes' AND t1.deleted<>1 AND t1.pool_id IN(0,1) 
    AND t3.reallocated<>'yes'
  group by t1.cfid) a
where d < NOW();
```

Comment: will above query count only those files that have not been worked till yesterday and leave those files worked today? @Fabricator

Comment: @leboMagma, test it out. If it doesn't work please post the table schema, test sample, and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aggregate functions in a `where` clause. If you want to do that, you need to:

1. Define grouping fields (i.e. add a `group by` clause)
2. Put any condition on grouped or aggregated fields in a `having` clause.

The correct syntax for a `select` query is:

```
SELECT -- Your fields and/or expressions
FROM -- Your data sources (tables, views and/or subqueries), and joins
WHERE -- Conditions on the "raw" data
GROUP BY -- Grouping fields
HAVING -- Conditions on grouped and/or aggregated data
ORDER BY -- Ordering fields
```

---

If you want the `task_list` records for which the last `task_date` is 24 hours old:

```
select id, max(task_date) as max_task_date
from task_list
where 
    task_date <= date_add(now(), interval -1 day)
    -- maybe you need something like: task_date <= date_add(curdate(), interval -1 day)
group by id;
```

I leave to you the rest... you can join this result with your other tables to get the info you need.

Comment: how do i achieve above please?

Comment: de you have multiple records in `task_list` with the same `id` and different date?